# External user should be able to view only his records in a salesforce community

Tags: community

We have created a salesforce community and expect the external user to view only his records. But in our case, he is able to view all the records. How can we sort this out.

Comment: What kind of user license is for external user....also check sharing setting for that object for external user

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set OWD to Private for External Access.
Use sharing set settings under community settings to give access to community user based on a criteria. To this need to include your community user profile and select the objects to which sharing must apply and setup sharing criteria.